# What process could lead to a sampling distribution of the mean that is approximately skew normal

Tags: sampling, mean, survey, central-limit-theorem

I have a data set representing guest ratings of various hotels. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the ratings given by individual guests, only to the mean guest rating for each particular hotel. The mean ratings (which are on a 0-100 scale) are quite heavily left-skewed with a peak around 70. If I look at the mean-rating data in terms of the number of guests that the hotels accommodate, a larger number of guest seems to result in a bunching-up (obviously a layman's term) around 70 but retaining the skew.

What sort of stochastic process (if any) might give rise to this kind of data. Clearly it must be a sampling process, or perhaps a rating process, that violates the assumptions that underpin the Central Limit Theorem, but although I tried various approaches to simulating the data in R I have not succeeded.

Comment: Perhaps the hotel has tour groups or other large groups of people that travel together who give similar ratings.  I suspect that the ratings guest are giving are not independent.

Comment: On the face of it, that sounds plausible. The guests who stay at any one time are might have similar good, or bad, experience that are different from the guests who stay on another occasion. But how exactly does that translate into distributions, sampling, and the final result?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) is misrepresented by many elementary books. The CLT says nothing whatever about what may happen at any finite sample size; it talks only about what happens to the distribution of a standardized sample mean (or a standardized sum) in the limit as sample size *goes to infinity* -- under certain conditions.

Means from very large samples -- in the thousands -- may sometimes still be quite skew.

It is typically the case that skewness of sample means tends to be smaller than skewness of the population distribution of the original values that make it up (generally skewness of means reduces inversely with the square root of sample size).

A sufficiently skew population distribution of values will yield skew distribution of means.

However, a distinct possibility to consider in your case is that you likely have heterogeneous sub-populations of hotels. Individually the population distribution of each hotel might be only moderately skew and so if you went back and sampled new sets of guests for a given hotel many times that hotel's distribution of means may be only very mildly skew -- but each hotel is in a different place on the range of possible rating-values. It would be quite possible (even likely, I'd imagine) that the population-mean rating of many hotels are toward one end of the rating scale and the remainder are more scattered along the rest of the range of ratings, and the sample values you observe might to a substantial degree simply reflect that (i.e. that each hotel's sample mean is close to its population mean and hotels are simply different); large samples within each hotel won't change that.